# c# .net web application.. data doesn't save at the database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I working on a web application using SQL server express 2014. In there I'm used to set some data to a table.there's no errors occurring but data doesn't set to the table.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connect" connectionString="Data Source=LAKSHITHA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EMS1;Integrated Security =True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

here is my aspx.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class Reg2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString());


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LAKSHITHA/SQLEXPRESS ;Initial Catalog=EMS1;Integrated Security=true";
            con.Open();
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Epersonal " + " (Emp_Id,NIC,Gender,B_day,Nationality,Marital_status,Work_Role)values(@Emp_Id,@NIC,@Gender,@B_day,@Nationality,@Marital_status,@Work_Role)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_Id", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIC", nic.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@B_day", bday.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", ntionl.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marital_status", DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(" @Work_Role", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
            Response.Write("cannection made");
            Response.Redirect("log.aspx");
            // con.Open();
            con.Close();
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

[here is my table and tz attributes]
after setting the data there is no data in the database. In my logging form  I have connected the DB and in there I'm using a DB data and logging to the application
Can you please tell whats wrong in here>???

Comment: Well the code which exécutés the query is commented out: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: You need to do `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` before `Response.Write("cannection made");`

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the command. Also, wrap `SqlCommand` ad `SqlConnection` in `using` clauses.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ToString()) 
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Epersonal (Emp_Id,NIC,Gender,B_day,Nationality,Marital_status,Work_Role)values(@Emp_Id,@NIC,@Gender,@B_day,@Nationality,@Marital_status,@Work_Role)", con))
   {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_Id", TextBox1.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIC", nic.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@B_day", bday.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", ntionl.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marital_status", DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(" @Work_Role", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
          con.Open();
          Response.Write("cannection made");
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
Response.Redirect("log.aspx");
```

**EDIT:**

Is better to use `Add` instead of `AddWithValue`, to avoid errors when infering the correct Database type.
For example:

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nationality", SqlDbType.Varchar, 20).Value = ntion1.Text;  //Picked a random size of 20, use your specified size instead`

Use it with all of your values.